# glGetUniformLocation returns 23724032

Tags: opengl, c++, glsl

as the title says, I have a problem using **glGetUniformLocation** call that returns, for the following code, the value 23724032. I'm writing a little engine and the draw function of my models is:

```
void Model::draw()
{
    // enable the shader program
    m_material->enable();
    // set the current value of the ModelViewProjection matrix
    m_material->getShaderProgram()->uniform("u_mvp", getPose());
    // draw the mesh using VAO
    m_mesh->draw();
    // disable the shader program
    m_material->disable();
}
```

where

```
void ShaderProgram::uniform(std::string i_varName, glm::mat4& i_value)
{
    // get the location of the uniform variable in the shader program
    GLint loc = glGetUniformLocation(m_programId, i_varName.c_str());
    if(loc != -1)
        glUniformMatrix4fv(loc, 1, GL_FALSE, glm::value_ptr(i_value));
}
```

My shaders are very simple:

```
// vertex shader
#version 330

uniform mat4 u_mvp;

attribute vec4 i_position;
//attribute vec4 i_normal;
//attribute vec2 i_texcoords;

void main(void)
{
    gl_Position = u_mvp * i_position;
}
```

and

```
// fragment shader
#version 330

precision highp float;

void main(void)
{
    gl_FragColor = vec4(1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0);
}
```

So, I have a question: why I get this weird value from the **glGetUniformLocation** call?
I found this topic ([link](https://www.opengl.org/discussion_boards/printthread.php?t=179467&pp=10&page=1)) from the OpenGL discussion board, but I still don't understand why my code doesn't draw anything. If the Intel integrated video card uses its own ids for attributes and uniforms, why is this a problem? What I have to do to fix it?

Note that if I run my application on high performance (with the dedicated video card), the function returns 0 as expected.

My notebook is a HP Pavilion dv7 6c90el with a *ATI Radeon HD 7690M XT* and a *Intel 3000*.

Thanks.

Comment: _"Note that if I run my application on high performance (with the dedicated video card), the function returns 0 as expected."_ So does this mean that something is rendered too or do you still get nothing?

Comment: Note that nothing mandates uniform locations to be small consecutive integers. Your value is perfectly legal and not particular to your machine. This fun behavior of the Intel driver revealed bugs in my code, having mismatched the ideas of "uniform location" and "active uniform index".

Comment: **Soapy** : unfortunately no, the applications doesn't render anything. Maybe the problem concerns the view and projection matrices (ops).
**LarsViklund** : thanks. So, what do you recommend to avoid these errors?

Comment: @MarcoCarletti Okay, well I think @LarsViklund has answered your question. There is nothing wrong with the uniform location being `23724032` and it's probably not the reason for nothing being rendered. Are you getting the attribute location? ie getting using [`glGetAttribLocation`](https://www.khronos.org/opengles/sdk/docs/man/xhtml/glGetAttribLocation.xml) and enabling with [`glEnableVertexAttribArray`](https://www.khronos.org/opengles/sdk/docs/man/xhtml/glEnableVertexAttribArray.xml)

Comment: @Soapy : you are right. I'll update the answer when I'll find the bug in my code. Thanks for the help, and thanks to **LarsViklund** too :)

Comment: I found the error: the VAO and the indeces are all ok (even the funny value in the question title). I was wrong a glViewport call... Sorry for the waste of time!